How to download the data from elastic index to CSV format using Elastcdump
I'm trying to download data from elastic index data to CSV file. but i'm unable to find the proper approach. I'm able to download the data in a Json format using elastic dump but using CSV i didn't find the proper approach to download it.
I have seen this format in NPM documentation :
# Import data from CSV file into ES (using csvurls)
elasticdump \
  # csv:// prefix must be included to allow parsing of csv files
  # --input "csv://${file_path}.csv" \
  --input "csv:///data/cars.csv"
  --output=http://production.es.com:9200/my_index \
  --csvSkipRows 1    # used to skip parsed rows (this does not include the headers row)
  --csvDelimiter ";" # default csvDelimiter is ','

I just changed the input and output to get the data in of the form csv  but I'm getting errors. Can any one suggest the proper approach to get the data in CSV.
elasticdump \
      # csv:// prefix must be included to allow parsing of csv files
      # --input "csv://${file_path}.csv" \
      --input = http://production.es.com:9200/my_index \
      --output "csv:///data/cars.csv"
      
      --csvSkipRows 1    # used to skip parsed rows (this does not include the headers row)
      --csvDelimiter ";" # default csvDelimiter is ','

